# lmfit not performing as expected

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, lmfit

I'm writing a script that is going to be used to fit some photoluminescence spectra with custom models and after creating a script using SciPy I learned that setting bounds on the fitting parameters is much easier if lmfit (cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/intro.html) is used instead so I decided to use that instead. Below is a script I wrote to fit one spectra with one Gaussian function (using 2 Gaussian functions is better, but I wanted to start with a simpler case).

```
    from numpy import loadtxt, vstack, average, exp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import lmfit

def sub_BG(data_array):
    naujas_X = data_array[:,1]-average(data_array[1:10,1])
    return vstack((data_array[:,0], naujas_X)).T

def gauss(x, a1, b1, c1):
    return  a1 * exp(-(x- b1)**2/ (2*c1**2))
           #amp * exp(-(x-cen)**2 /wid) 


data="single_spectra.txt"

spectra = loadtxt(open(data, 'r'), skiprows=2)


spectra_beBG = sub_BG(spectra)

plt.plot(spectra_beBG[:,0],spectra_beBG[:,1],'g')


mod1 = lmfit.Model(gauss)

pars = lmfit.Parameters()
#             (Name,  Value,  Vary,   Min,  Max,  Expr)
pars.add_many(('a1', 590, True, None, None, None),
              ('b1', 500, True, None, None, None),
              ('c1', 20, True, None, None , None))

out  = mod1.fit(spectra_beBG[:,0], pars, x=spectra_beBG[:,1])

y = gauss(spectra_beBG[:,0], 
          out.best_values["a1"],
          out.best_values["b1"],
          out.best_values["c1"])


plt.plot(spectra_beBG[:,0], out.best_fit, "r--")
plt.plot(spectra_beBG[:,0], y, "b--")
print(out.fit_report())
```

This returns:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(gauss)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 77
    # data points      = 1024
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 28469283.530
    reduced chi-square = 27883.725
[[Variables]]
    a1:   561.593868 +/- 8.255604 (1.47%) (init= 590)
    b1:   100.129107 +/- 85.34384 (85.23%) (init= 500)
    c1:   1.3254e+06 +/- 7.23e+05 (54.52%) (init= 20)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
    C(b1, c1)                    = -0.892 
    C(a1, c1)                    = -0.763 
    C(a1, b1)                    =  0.685
```

[Graph output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QAsc.png)

If I change pars.add_many() to something closer to nature, for example:

```
pars.add_many(('a1', 590, True, 550, 630, None),
              ('b1', 500, True, 450, 650, None),
              ('c1', 30, True, 20, 70 , None))
```

I get this:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(gauss)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 147
    # data points      = 1024
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 304708538.428
    reduced chi-square = 298441.272
[[Variables]]
    a1:   629.999937 +/- 0        (0.00%) (init= 590)
    b1:   475.821359 +/- 0        (0.00%) (init= 500)
    c1:   70         +/- 0        (0.00%) (init= 30)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
```

[Graph output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MPiA.png)

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, should that be

```
out  = mod1.fit(spectra_beBG[:,1], pars, x=spectra_beBG[:,0])
```

That is, you want to fit "y", and pass in the "pars" and "x" array to help calculate the model with those parameters and independent variables.